# empty WP_Query object on local install

Tags: wp-query, localhost

I just realized, that i got a complete ***empty WP_Query object*** on my plain wordpress install. I reseted the DB, deactivated all plugins and activated TwentyTen as theme, but the complete Object simply is empty on every request (public & admin facing). It doesn't matter if i request the "*Hello World*" post or a `404`. Everything is empty. What reason could this have?

**Edit 1**
This is how i inspect **WP_Query**:

```
// inserted on top of the functions.php file, 
// so it's equal to a function hooked into the 'after_setup_theme' hook  
// i also tried other hooks (which should make no difference) and got the same result.
    echo '<pre>'; 
        print_r($GLOBALS['wp_query']); 
    echo '</pre>';
```

This is the result from the `print_r();`

```
WP_Query Object
(
    [query] => 
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
        )

    [tax_query] => 
    [queried_object] => 
    [queried_object_id] => 
    [request] => 
    [posts] => 
    [post_count] => 0
    [current_post] => -1
    [in_the_loop] => 
    [post] => 
    [comments] => 
    [comment_count] => 0
    [current_comment] => -1
    [comment] => 
    [found_posts] => 0
    [max_num_pages] => 0
    [max_num_comment_pages] => 0
    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_archive] => 
    [is_date] => 
    [is_year] => 
    [is_month] => 
    [is_day] => 
    [is_time] => 
    [is_author] => 
    [is_category] => 
    [is_tag] => 
    [is_tax] => 
    [is_search] => 
    [is_feed] => 
    [is_comment_feed] => 
    [is_trackback] => 
    [is_home] => 
    [is_404] => 
    [is_comments_popup] => 
    [is_paged] => 
    [is_admin] => 
    [is_attachment] => 
    [is_singular] => 
    [is_robots] => 
    [is_posts_page] => 
    [is_post_type_archive] => 
    [parsed_tax_query] => 
)
```

Comment: How are you looking at WP_Query and what do you see when the page loads?

Comment: @Greg: Thanks for your answer. I updated the Q. When i load the page i see the empty WP_Query object (see above). Setup is a complete vanilla wp.

Comment: Ya know `$wp_query` usually has scope, you can generally just do this straight in your template files(global if inside a function) ... `print_r( $wp_query );` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's empty because you're looking at it before it has a chance to be populated.

The top of functions.php is too early. You should be doing it in a 'template_redirect' action.

Or, better yet, use the Debug Bar plugin.

Comment: Oh, haha! I was pretty confused looking at this. Yea... maybe i'm just too tired after a .5kg steak. Thanks, mister :)

Comment: Short Q (brain still not working). When should i trigger the function to show the query in the admin UI? Thanks.

Comment: I use 'admin_notices'.